# python, map name from a list to a list of dict

Tags: python

I have the following list and list of dicts:

```
data = [dict(position=1, value=150.3), 
        dict(position=0, value=28.5), 
        dict(position=2, value=1050.3)]

names = ["CL", "ES", "EUR"]
```

I would like to map the values of the list into the list of dicts so they match the value stated in the key "position" of the dict - to get the following result:

```
data = [dict(name="ES", position=1, value=150.3), 
        dict(name="CL", position=0, value=28.5), 
        dict(name="EUR", position=2, value=1050.3)]
```

Is there any "smart" and pythonic way to achieve that?

Comment: It seems the key position starts from `1` rather than `0` (the Python convention). Is this a typo or part of the problem specification?

Comment: @CristiFati yes i am using the `position`value to map the list to the list of dict

Comment: @Cong Ma  ok edited

Answer (score 2):

First of all, please present your question in actual Python form. `dict` is a type; the way you represent dictionaries in Python is with `{}`.

Also, you don't have "a dict and list", you have two lists, one of which consists of three dictionaries. So:

```
data = [
  {'position': 1, 'value': 150.3},
  {'position': 0, 'value': 28.5},
  {'position': 2, 'value': 1050.3}
]

names = ["CL", "ES", "EUR"]
```

So, given that you do have lists, there is no concern about ordering. A simple loop will give you what you want:

```
for d in data:
    d['name'] = names[d['position']]
```

This updates `data` in place:

```
>>> data
[{'position': 1, 'name': 'ES', 'value': 150.3}, {'position': 0, 'name': 'CL', 'value': 28.5}, {'position': 2, 'name': 'EUR', 'value': 1050.3}]
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `dict(position = 1, value=150.3)`, and it saves typing a load of quotes.  `{...}` is an expression of type `dict`. `dict(args)` invokes the constructor for an object of type dict. The end result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension and dictionary [update](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_update.htm):

```
data = [dict(position = 2, value=150.3), 
        dict(position = 1, value = 28.5), 
        dict(position=3, value=1050.3)]

names = ['CL', 'ES', 'EUR']

# Sort names according to "position" value of the dictionary
sorted_names = [names[idx] for idx in map(lambda x: x['position'], data)]
# Update modifies inplace
_ = [data[idx].update({'name' : el}) for idx, el in enumerate(sorted_names)]
```

Which gives the expected output:

```
data
[{'name': 'ES', 'position': 2, 'value': 150.3},
 {'name': 'CL', 'position': 1, 'value': 28.5},
 {'name': 'EUR', 'position': 3, 'value': 1050.3}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
data = [{"position": 2, "value": 150},
        {"position": 1, "value": 200}]
names = ["CL", "ES"]

for item in data:
    item["name"] = names[item["pos"] - 1]
```

Where we go through all the dictionaries in the list, then for each dictionary we set the `"name"` key to be equal to the value in `data` at the position described in `item["pos"]` minus 1.

This of course assumes your data is clean and all items in `data` correctly map to items in `names`.

If this is not the case, use a try-except:

```
for item in data:
    try:
        item["name"] = names[item["pos"] - 1]
    except IndexError:
        item["name"] = None
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `update` method on the dictionary elements in the list, if you like the keyword-argument convention, as the style of your question suggests.

```
for item in data:
    item.update(name=names[item["position"]])
```

Answer (score 0):

A one liner implementation using list comprehension.

```
print [dict(d.items()+[('name',names[d['position']-1])]) for d in data]
```